# How to do multi-linguistic sorting in HSQLDB?

Tags: sql, sorting, hsqldb

I'm using HSQLDB as the database and the database tables contain data from multiple languages. So, I'd like to know if there is anyway to do multi-linguistic sorting in HSQLDB. Something similar to what  [Oracle Database](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/server.920/a96529/ch4.htm) has done here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sort the result set from a SELECT using any collation that you choose.

If you want an index on the column of the database, if you have just a few languages, this is possible using GENERATED columns. For each language, create its own GENERATED column with its specific collation. Also add a column to indicate the language. The GENERATED expression should return the column value if it is in the given language or elese NULL. Then add an index on the GENERATED column. See `GENERATED ALWAYS` under http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/databaseobjects-chapt.html#dbc_table_creation

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was already aware of passing the language through collate, but what I'm looking for is if there is any way to sort multi-lingual data, i.e., sorting based on not just one language but all the supported languages.  Something similar to this: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/server.920/a96529/ch4.htm

Comment: The chapter you refer to covers many things, some of which are supported by HSQLDB with collations. It's not clear what you mean by multi-linguistic sorting. It is never possible to sort by all languages at the same time as there are conflicts in sorting. The default HSQLDB collation sorts by Unicode characters.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification that we can't sort by all languages at the same time. I've opted the approach of using collation to sort the data.